# Is there a way to introduce a delay in a system analyzed with the octave control package

Tags: octave

I'm trying to analyze the system

```
 20*e(0.9*s)
-------------
   (s+10)
```

using GNU octave and the control package, but I cannot find the way to introduce the exponential (the `exp` octave function does not work).

The code I tried to write is

```
pkg load control
s = tf('s')
g = 20*exp(0.9*s)/(s+10)
```

but the following error is shown: `error: exp: not defined for class`

I tried searching the web a bit, without success.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In MATLAB, you can do it as: `sys = tf(20,[1 10],'InputDelay',0.9)`. Let me know if it work sin Octave and I will add it as an asnwer.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I'm sorry, but I think it's not compatible since I get the error `error: tf: set: key name 'InputDelay' is unknown`

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything in the octave docs unfortunately.

Comment: You need `exp(-0.9*s)`, right? and not `exp(0.9*s)`

Comment: In "devel/PROJECTS" there are some notes:"Missing Features: time delays (challenging). Add delays  exp (-T*s)  indelay, outdelay, stdelay, ..." so I would say it's not implemented yet (also pade). So feel free to implement it!